# Разница между фрэймворком, библиотекой и API?

Tags: framework, библиотеки, любой-язык, терминология

Так в чём на самом деле разница между **фрэймворком**, **библиотекой** и **API**?
Есть мнение, что всё это близкие понятия, везде есть классы и методы которые можно встроить в клиентский код.
И всё же, похоже есть существенные отличия?

Comment: Метафорически — библиотека — это часть приложения. Фрэймворк — это скелет,  API – внешние части указанного приложения.  Фрэймворк, ко всему прочему, в отличии от API использует инверсию управления.

Comment: В дополнении.
http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/54451/library-vs-framework-vs-api
Ответы трёх участников (@Makarenko_I_V,  @Alex Krass, @VladD) были весьма неплохие. Лучший ответ имхо VladD - потому что в ответе использован язык метафор, понятный для новичков.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Начнём с **API**. Это самый простой вариант: возможность для приложения обратиться к коду вне этого приложения. Это набор функциональности для того, чтобы заставить внешнюю для программы сущность сделать свою работу.

Пример из реальной жизни: у вас есть в квартире водопровод, а API — телефон сантехника, который этот водопровод может починить, если надо.

Теперь, **библиотека** — это готовый к использованию набор кода, который бежит в контексте приложения, и точно так же выполняет свою работу. То есть библиотека становится при подключении частью приложения. Разница между библиотекой и API может быть довольно тонкой: например, WinAPI предоставляет функциональность, которая в общем-то иногда происходит и в рамках процесса. Тем не менее, это считается обращением к внешней для приложения платформе.

Пример из реальной жизни: вы сами не сколачиваете шкаф, а покупаете домой готовый, ставите в свою квартиру и пользуетесь им. Шкаф — ваша подключаемая библиотека.

Ну и **фреймворк** — его функции, в отличие от библиотеки, не вызываются вами, а наоборот, ваш код вызывается из него. Фреймворк можно представить себе в виде полуфабриката приложения, к которому вы дописываете нужную функциональность сами.

Пример из реальной жизни: вы покупаете почти готовую квартиру, а мебель, обои и шкафы добавляете сами. Квартира — ваш фреймворк, она уже почти готова. Вы не можете так просто переделать число комнат или превратить её в корабль, вместо этого вы только добавляете внутреннюю функциональность: паркетный пол, махровый халат в ванной и кота.

Comment: Я бы сказал, что конкретная библиотека это реализация API

Answer (score 15):

Если Вы попользуетесь каждым поймете разницу.

### API:

Чаще всего подразумевает интерфейс взаимодействия. Используется для работы с независимыми сервисами. Допустим, Вы хотите выкладывать видео на YouTube, то будете пользоваться их функциональностью через API.

### Библиотека:

Чаще всего набор готовых классов, методов, решений типичных задач. Заточеных под что то определенное. Допустим, Вы хотите распознавать лица на фотографиях (собственноручно, не используя сторонние сервисы), то установите какую-то OpenCV и будете ее использовать, что бы не изобретать велосипед заново.

### Фреймворк:

Чаще всего включают в себя библиотеки для удобства. И предоставляют Вам готовый **шаблон/ы** приложения, реализуя паттерны проектирования (MVC, MVVC или другие). Фреймворк обычно состоит из готовых модулей, которые между собой жестко связаны (используют интерфейсы друг-друга), при разработке своего модуля необходимо реализовывать интерфейсы для прощей интеграции своих модулей.

Comment: как интересно. Пользуюсь всем, но доходит медленно.

Comment: А как-нибудь более метафорически, можете пояснить? 
Можете освятить момент, чего нет в фрэймворке, что обязательно присутствует в API (или наоборот)? Может ли програмный продукт быть и фрэймворком и API? 
Например по фрэймворку, не очень ясно, с шаблоном, это как? Имеется ввиду, что в фрэймворке по определению уже написана простейшая программа (типа Hello World)? И я так понимаю, в вашем последнем предложении паттерны = шаблоны, верно? 
Имхо, вопрос важный, ещё сотня людей просмотрит ваш ответ после. Поподробнее плиз.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin, по крайней мере термин [API](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/API) хорошо описан в вике (ну, с [фреймворком](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA) там тоже неплохо). В 2-х словах API это соглашения, которые реализует библиотека, а фреймворк это набор софта (в т.ч. библиотек) и правил его использования, который диктует, как д.б. построено приложение (т.е. некий каркас, в который Вы встраиваете свои части). / Ну, а библиотека? Вообще говоря, просто сборище подпрограмм (обычно согласованных), которые вы можете вызывать.

Comment: @avp прекрасно, я уже начинаю чуть-чуть понимать. А может ли одна программа быть одновременно API и фрэймворком?

Comment: @avp по сути, любая IDE является **framework**ом. Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @AndrewKachalin, нет, не правильно. IDE это *средство разработки*.  Конкретная(-ый? -ое?) IDE может "знать" о каких-то фреймворках и вести вас по правильному пути использования выбранного фреймворка.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin, Мне кажется Вам следует понять, что Ваша программа может быть просто "Hellow World" (далее **HW**), может быть тем-же HW написаным на **фреймворке**, может иметь **API** по которому, кто угодно другой может получить сообщение **HW**, и может использовать **библиотеки** для вывода сообщения. **Сначала есть программа все остальное это независимо / опционально**.

Comment: а зачем большой шрифт и чёрточка после заголовка?

Answer (score 11):

**API** - это интерфейс взаимодействия с программой извне. У Вас есть сам по себе какой-то готовый продукт и он представляется черным ящиком и Вы хотите, что бы им могли пользоваться другие программы. Вы определяете методы взаимодействия с ним и описываете их, а сторонние программы им пользуются. Само по себе понятие очень широкое и чаще его все же используют по отношению к удаленным сервисам и запросам вне основного приложения. Грубо говоря API - описание взаимодействия с черным ящиком, что бы он сделал Вам то или иное действие.

**Библиотека** - это сборка различный функций и подпрограмм, которая может быть перенесена и использоваться потом в различных приложениях. Основная идея в том, что они переносимы между приложениями и могут быть многократно использованы без изменений.

**Фреймворк** - это каркас для будущего приложения, в котором собраны все основные необходимые детали: библиотеки, структура, начальный код и т.д. Можно сказать, это минимальная заготовка, на основе которой Вы будете дописывать функционал и строить дальше приложение. Ваше приложение будет работать за счет того, что уже есть и заботливо для Вас заготовлено.

Comment: Про фреймвёк не согласен. Это определение уже на starter kit тянет, а не на framework.

Comment: @Qwertiy а фреймворк это не тот же Starter Kit под определенный вид приложений? Даются начальные детали и на их основе собираешь свой паровозик с доделками, используя моторчик и колесики.

Comment: Неа. Даётся идеология архитектуры и нечто, что обеспечивает её работу. При этом фреймвёк вполне может подключаться единственным файлом, как и библиотека.

Answer (score 7):

Библиотека как правило маленькая, создана для чего-то определенного, как правило, одной цели. Например, библиотека календарь на js, график на winforms.

API - это выставленный напоказ интерфейс системы: методы, классы и тд, которыми другие люди могут пользоваться.

Framework - большая система, охватывает многие вопросы по какой-либо теме. Например, .NET Framework. Это куча библиотек для самых разных нужд. Можно писать как веб-приложения, так и winforms, wpf, wcf и другие.

Comment: спасибо. ваше мнение очень важно для нас.

Answer (score 2):

Если на пальцах, то так:

- Библиотека - это какая-то внешняя логика, к которой ваш код может свободно обращаться, чтобы дёргать некий функционал.
- Фреймворк - это какой-то готовый каркас, в рамки которого вы должны вписать ваш код.
- АПИ - это пульт управления, который некоторая система выставляет наружу, чтобы другие системы могли к ней обращаться.

Answer (score 1):

API это [паттерн](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Библиотеки и фреймворки предоставляют API.

API может создаваться на базе фреймворка.

Фреймворк состоит из библиотек или являет собой паттерн их соединения.

Библиотека может собираться фреймворком платформы.

Answer (score 0):

Api (appliation interface)  - доступ к функционалу приложения. Библиотека (сборка)  - отдельный модуль содержащий набор классов или методов.  Ну и framework это не просто набор функционала как api, sdk или библиотека - это полноценная среда разработки,  помимо набора классов и методов которые могут быть использованы в вашем приложении фрэймворк дает, нужное подчеркнуть, компилятор, интерпретатор, менеджер пакетов, декомпилятор и многое другое. Например. Net,  nodejs, java являются фрэймворками.

Answer (score 0):

поправьте, если не прав ХОТЬ В ЧЕМ-ТО.
Библиотека (*.dll)- тупо примитивно ДРАЙВЕРА.(Отличие драйвера от программы - отсутствие в коде драйвера точки входа (так называемой и всеми любимой функции "main(){}" ...). без psv main(){} программа становится библиотекой (набором классов).
Фрэймвок - это СДК, использующий АПИ(которая в свою очередь использует *.dll библиотеки/драйвера)
Фрэймворк - это SDK, работающий с помощью API.